# Bind NSArrayControllers ManagedObjectContext after loading from nib

Tags: core-data, nib, nsarraycontroller

Hello I am trying to bind the NSManagedObjectContext of my NSArrayController later by code.
The controller gets loaded in the nib without a bound context. But I have a NSTableView bound to the array controller. I want the table to remain empty until I loaded some data into the context (and not show the old data in the context on launch). When I launch the app i get this error:

[Cannot perform operation without a managed object context](http://pastebin.com/4H1quLaQ)

Is this just not possible? Do I have to work around that or am I doing it wrong?
I thought the controller would return nil without a context.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you would be better served programmatically binding the `NSArrayController` to the `NSTableView` once the context is populated appropriately?

Here's Apple documentation of the [NSKeyValueBindingCreation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSKeyValueBindingCreation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) informal protocol.

Comment: I hoped there is a way to get around this but it seems as if I got to do it in code...